Is the statement: "Winners don't quit and quitters don't win" a tautology?
I was reading How To Think Like a Mathematician and came across the following question:

Is the phrase "Winners don't quit and quitters don't win" a tautology?

My answer was no. I translated the statement into logical form as:
$$ (W \implies \neg Q) \land (Q \implies \neg W) $$
Here:

( W ): "The person is a Winner"
( Q ): "The person is a Quitter"

If someone is both a Winner (W) and a Quitter (Q), the statement evaluates to false. So, it cannot be a tautology.
However, the answer in the book's mark scheme says it is a tautology, which has left me confused. I've looked online but couldn't find an explanation.
Could someone help clarify why my reasoning is incorrect?
Thank you in advance!

How can someone be a winner and a quitter?

@J.W.Tanner You have to know when to hold 'em, know when to fold 'em, ...

Using contraposition, $(A\implies B)\implies(\neg B\implies \neg A)$ so if I take $A=W$ and $B=\neg Q$, I get to conclude the second statement i.e., $(Q \implies \neg W)$ from the first one i.e., $(W \implies \neg Q)$.

I thought being a winner and a quitter is something with the English language but doesn't translate the same with logic. I'm not sure, I'm kind of new to this stuff.

What does it mean "be a Winner"?  I'm not sure that's a statement.

What happens if the rules of the game state that the first player to quit some activity is the winner?

The identifications of "don't quit" with "is not a quitter" and "don't win" with "is not a winner" are questionable. What is the status of someone who sometimes wins and sometimes doesn't win, or sometimes quits and sometimes doesn't quit?

The issue here is not an interpretation of what it means to be a quitter or a winner. We have two propositional variables that can each be either true or false. The real question is: is Ahmed's interpretation of the statement correct or isn't it? Would you translate that sentence into a conjunction or an equivalence? The answers below indicate that the interpretation should be an equivalence, but how? How does "and" become $\iff$ instead of $\land$?

No, a tautology is a statement that is always true.
Let $~A~$ denote the statement "Winners Don't Quit". 
Let $~B~$ denote the statement "Quitters Don't Win". 
Let $~C~$ denote the statement $~A \iff B.~$
Statements $~A~$ and $~B~$ are logically equivalent, and neither statement is always true.  That is, sometimes a quitter (accidentally) wins.  For example, what happens if two quitters compete against each other, and ties are not permitted.
However, statement $~C~$ is always true (and therefore a tautology), specifically because $~A \implies B~$ and $~B \implies A.$

Why is Statement C, $A \iff B$ and not $A \land B$?

@Ahmed Because the statement $~[ ~A ~\wedge ~B ~] ~$ is not always true.

That was @Ahmed's point. He reasoned that the statement was a conjunction, not an equivalence. The real question becomes, how do you justify interpreting the English word "and" differently than a conjunction? Or, is he right? He says the English statement is not a tautology.

@JohnDouma I am confused here.  I specified my statement C to represent (in English) the following statement:  [the assertion "Winners Don't Quit" is true] if and only if [the assertion "Quitters Don't Win" is true].  So, my specification for statement C contains no conjunction.  Therefore, I don't understand Ahmed's point, or your comment.

The statement that he is asked about says "winners never quit and quitters never win". Why does that mean $\iff$? He interpreted that as $\land$. Why is that interpretation incorrect? Saying that it is incorrect because it doesn't work is not a valid argument.

@JohnDouma I think that you have misinterpreted Ahmed's comment-question.  Ahmed asked why I constructed statement C as I did, rather than constructing it as $~A \wedge B.~$  My response was that I constructed statement C as I did, because the alternate construction of statement C, as $~A  \wedge B,~$ would not have been a tautology.  So, again, I don't understand your comment.  That is, I rejected using the statement $~A \wedge B,~$ so I rejected having statement C involve a conjunction.  So, why is it relevant to discuss a conjunctive statement, since that statement has been rejected?

Your reason is essentially that you interpreted the problem so that the author was correct. That was his question. He says the statement is not a tautology. He, as I did, interpreted "and" as $\land$. It seems that you agree that $A\land B$ is not a tautology.  The question remains: why is $(W\implies\lnot Q)\land (Q\implies\lnot W)$ an incorrect interpretation of the statement?

@JohnDouma "Your reason is essentially that you interpreted the problem so that the author was correct" : false.  I have interpreted the problem so that the author is mistaken.  Since $~A~$ and $~B~$ are logically equivalent statements, the statement $~A \wedge B~$ is a tautology if and only if the statement $~A~$ is a tautology.  I demonstrated that the statement $~A~$ is not a tautology, thus demonstrating that the author was wrong.  Perhaps you might re-read my answer.

I don't see you explicitly saying that the author's statement is false. See Robert's answer. @Ahmed Please clarify what is true here. Does my interpretation of this differ from yours? I've been wrong before.

@JohnDouma If statement $~A~$ by itself is not a tautology then statement $ ~[ ~A ~~~\text{and} ~~~\text{any statement} ~] ~$ can not possibly be a tautology.

The statement is certainly not a tautology.  What is a tautology is
$(W \implies \neg Q) \iff (Q \implies \neg W)$
